# Declaring a global array extension to check an empty list leads to a compiler error

Tags: typescript

I learning Typescript and I'm trying to create convenient features with the Array extension. This example below works on the Typescript playground but my editor throws **TypeError: ... is not a function.** All other extensions work well but read an empty list I can't in this way. I tried many solutions from StackOverflow but it does not work anyway. Someone can explain how it works?

```js
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        isNotEmpty(): boolean;
        isEmpty(): boolean;
    }
}

Array.prototype.isNotEmpty = function <T>(this: T[]): boolean {
    return !!this.length;
};

Array.prototype.isEmpty = function <T>(this: T[]): boolean {
    return !this.length;
};

export { };
```

Comment: Is this error occurring when you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new declarations file, e.g. `Array.d.ts` with the declaration you're adding:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        isNotEmpty(): boolean;
        isEmpty(): boolean;
    }
}
```

Then under the include property in your tsconfig.json add the path to that `.d.ts` file like so:

```
  "include": [
    "src/*.ts", // Or wherever your source code lies
    "Array.d.ts" // <- this is the new declaration 
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I tried similar methods, and your example throws the same error. What is strange, this work in the typescript playground, but my editor doesn't want to compile this. Maybe some configurations I have wrong.

Comment: I've tried this in my editor and it definitely works so it's likely your editor, try restarting vscode

Comment: Probably I get this error only in debug mode. When I debugging my vscode extension. I not tried run this in the terminal.

Comment: Sorry just to confirm, are you saying that the error is at runtime (as in the isEmpty doesnt return a boolean) or that typescripts intellisense doesn't pick it up, sounds like you're saying the latter now. I just tested in my vscode extension and if you don't already, then make sure to include the src code in your includes (I'll update the answer to reflect this)

Comment: My problem is that `isEmpty()` does not return a boolean and leads to compile error TypeError: arr.isEmpty is not a function. It's very strange that you have no problem I tried everything that you recommended, but I still have an error. Some other extensions work well from the same file but what about `isEmpty()`, not work. I found a solution by adding import, ex: `import './extensions/array.extension';` then works without problems as expected. But I want it to work globally.